# how to express the nonlinear anisotropic coeff of convection term

Tags: python, fipy

The term I want to express is a part of N-S equation.
[u,v are the component of flow velocity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIBZZ.png)

Is the following code correct?

```
u = CellVariable(mesh=mesh,hasOld=1,value=0.0)
v = CellVariable(mesh=mesh,hasOld=1,value=0.0)

coeff_con = FaceVariable(mesh=mesh,rank=1)
coeff_con.setValue([u.arithmeticFaceValue,v.arithmeticFaceValue])

ConvectionTerm(coeff=coeff_con,var=u)
```

I will reset the value of coeff_con whenever the u, v updates.

Answer (score 1):

As an incomplete piece of solving Navier-Stokes, what you have is OK. You will need to update `coeff_con` after every sweep. This won't result in stable solutions. Our [Stokes](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/flow/generated/examples.flow.stokesCavity.html) example shows how to implement the SIMPLE pressure correction algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
Maybe  I do not express the question clearly, and I re-edit it.
To your first reason, I reset the value whenever u, v updates .
To your second reason , I define the coeff_con as a rank-1 FaceVariable before I set value to it.
Then, can the code work correctly?
Thanks for your help again.

Comment: I have revised my answer based on your revised question